# Why there is no constant wave-function of an electron, while all the electrons are same?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, wavefunction

The mass and charge of all electrons are same, so why don't we have a single wavefunction for electrons.

Comment: How would the fact that all electrons are the same imply that there exists only one single wavefunction? In the case of nonrelativistic QM, the charge does not even enter and the mass enters only in some coefficients, so the wavefunction does not care very much about charge and mass - it only cares about the potential $V(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electrons are indeed all the same in the sense that they are all excitations of the same electron quantum field. However they can have different momenta and energy. The momentum is obtained from the wavefunction using the [momentum operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator):

$$ \hat p = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} $$

And the energy from the [Hamiltonian operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(quantum_mechanics)):

$$ \hat H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + V $$

And for these to return the differing energies and momenta of different electrons clearly those electrons have to have different wavefunctions.

The wavefunction is generally used to describe single electrons, or groups of a few interacting electrons, and those electrons will have differing properties like the momentum and energy already mentioned, and also potential energy, spin orientation and probably others I haven't thought of. All these different quantities have to be reflected in different wavefunctions.

However all electrons are ultimately described by a single mathematical object called the electron quantum field. In this sense you are correct that there is a single object that describes all electrons - it's just not the wavefunction.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned a bit more strongly that the electron quantum field is a _mathematical_ object, **not** necessarily a _physical_ one. It's just a contributing part of a model used to make predictions.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist yes, that's true, and I say that in my last paragraph. But the operator field presumably describes some physical object even though we don't know what that object is. Whether you use the term *quantum field* to refer to the operator field or the physical object is personal preference. I'm being deliberately vague here since if we get into discussions of what operator fields are that would take the answer to a level hopelessly above the level of the question.

Comment: Very fair, and upvoted comment. I've been noticing a lot of questions on Physics SE as of late that conflate mathematical constructs with physical constructs, so I've been making an effort to throw in my two pence where possible to try to ameliorate this common source of confusion, thanks also for a good answer